# Checking if multiple variables are all the same value in R

Tags: r

I know there are ways of checking if multiple variables are equal to each other using `all.equal`, but that's not what I'm asking here. Let's say I have a function `f(v, w = NULL, x = NULL, y = NULL, z = NULL)` and I want to know if `w`, `x`, `y`, and `z` are all NULL. the only way I know of to do this is with `all(is.null(w), is.null(x), is.null(y), is.null(z))`. Is there an easier way? I'm envisioning a vectorised method like `all(c(w, x, y, z), is.null)`, but I think of anything. `sapply(c(w, x, y, z), is.null)` just returns an empty list.

Comment: maybe `all(sapply(formals(f)[-1], is.null)`

Comment: `all(sapply(list(w,x,y,z), is.null))` seems to work - use `list(w,x,y,z)` instead of `c(w,x,y,z)`

Comment: Well done Richard and latemail. Both options work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `list` instead of `c` when creating your group to test against:

```
w <- x <- y <- z <- NULL

sapply(list(w,x,y,z), is.null)
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

all(sapply(list(w,x,y,z), is.null))
#[1] TRUE
```

seems to work.

As to why `c` doesn't work, consider:

```
c(NULL,NULL,1,NULL)
#[1] 1
c(NULL,NULL,NULL)
#NULL
```